# mysql query link from table1 where this link hasn't exist in table2 and table3

Tags: php, mysql

I want to making a MySQL query that gets a link from table1 and checks to see if this link exists in table2 and table3.

Now I am doing 2 queries, but I would like to combine the 2 query into 1, and guarantee 10 results are returned?  (After the first, currently, if mysql_num_rows($rez)>0, the return result would be less 10)

Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,link FROM table1 WHERE Order By id DESC LIMIT 0,10"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $rez = mysql_query("(SELECT link FROM table2 WHERE link='".mysql_real_escape_string($row['link'])."') UNION (SELECT link FROM table3 WHERE link='".mysql_real_escape_string($row['link'])."')");
  if(mysql_num_rows($rez)==0){
    //do stuff with $row['link'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-queries to acomplish this

`SELECT id, link FROM table1 WHERE (link IN (SELECT link FROM table2)) OR (link IN (SELECT link FROM table3)) LIMIT 10`

My format might be slightly off, and it seems like there's probably a better way to do that query, but check out sub-queries as I think those will get you in the direction you want to go

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking to find rows that don't exist in table2 or table3.
If you're trying to find rows that exist in either, use the query posted above.

```
SELECT id, link FROM table1 WHERE link NOT IN (SELECT link FROM table2) AND link NOT IN (SELECT link FROM table3) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```